# AnimatorListener playing sound multiple times

Tags: java, android

the `getProgressbar();`playing `mediaPlayer.start();` multiple times because the `btnSubmit` has to be click multiple times. Iam using Horizontal proggres bar and works good but the `mediaPlayer` was not.

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        getProgressBar();

        }


    });

private void getProgressBar() {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            mediaPlayer.start();

           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });


        animator.start();

}
```